# how to recover data that was lost

Tags: 14.04

i had windows8 os in my laptop HP Pavilion G series.it was partitioned in c: d: e: drives.i installed ubuntu 14.04.all the partitions are gone and ubuntu is showing a single disk.i last all the data can i recover that data.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I had success using [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).
There is a detailed [list of instructions](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step), so I won't go into details.
However, for me, it has only been a matter of selecting the appropriate items from the menu and to wait for an hour so for the program to scan my disk.